# what is the "appropriate value of type `Integer`" and can I write one; also newtypes

Tags: haskell, typeclass, newtype

Haskell 2010 report section 6.4.1 says

> An integer literal represents the application of the function `fromInteger` to the appropriate value of type `Integer`.

What does that "appropriate value" look like? Can I write it in source Haskell? I could of course write

```
x :: Integer
x = 4
```

But that equation is equivalent to

```
x = (fromInteger 4) :: Integer
```

**Edit:** hmm to avoid infinite regress that should probably be

```
x = (fromInteger 4?) :: Integer
```

in which `4?` is the mysterious value `4` at type `Integer`.

so it's selecting the `Integer` overloading of `fromInteger`. The type of the literal (in the original `x = 4`) is still `4 :: Num a => a`, it's not type `Integer`.

I'm thinking about this wrt `newtype`s:

```
{-# LANGUAGE  GeneralisedNewtypeDeriving  #-}

newtype Age = MkAge Int  deriving (Num, Eq, Ord, Show)
                        -- fromInteger is in Num
y :: Age
y = 4  
z = (4 + 5 :: Age)      -- no decl for z, inferred :: Age
```

If I ask to `show y` I see `MkAge 4`; if I ask to `show x` I see plain `4`. So is there some invisible constructor for `Integer`s?

Supplementary q for `newtype`s: since I can write `z = (4 + 5 :: Age)` is the constructor `MkAge` really necessary?

```
mkAge2 :: Age -> Age
mkAge2 = id

w = mkAge2 4

mkAge3 :: Integer -> Age
mkAge3 = fromInteger

u = mkAge3 4
```

seems to work just as well, if I want something prefix.

Comment: `fromInteger` is used to convert an `Integer` to a numerical type (like `Int` for example). The "appropriate value" means a value in the target type that has the same value as the `Integer`.

Comment: No. Read the quote from the Report. "the appropriate value of type `Integer`".

Comment: I think there is no Haskell syntax for _directly_ expressing the "appropriate value" the Report is referring to. It is a value that should be created by a Haskell implementation when a literal is found, and it will always be surrounded by an implicit `fromInteger`. This is a sort-of theoretical limitation which has no practical consequences, since `4 :: Integer` stands for `fromInteger the_actual_Integer_4 :: Integer` which evaluates to the same value `the_actual_Integer_4` represents. So, even if there is no syntax for `the_actual_Integer_4` it does not really matter. (It's a bit weird.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I write it in source Haskell?

Sort of.

You can write `4 :: Integer` but `4` is already an application of `fromInteger` to "an appropriate value". `:: Integer` only selects an appropriate overload for `fromInteger`. The application has type `Integer` though, so it can function like a magic monomorphic literal.

> ```
> newtype Age = MkAge Int  deriving (Num, Eq, Ord, Show)
> ```

You can write `4 :: Age` now and this is OK. This has nothing to do with what `Show` does. You can write your own `Show` instance that prints a plain `4` instead of `MkAge 4`. This is how `Show` instances for all the built-in types work. The following is GHC-specific, other implementations may have different details, but the general principles are likely to be the same.

```
Prelude> :i Int
data Int = GHC.Types.I# Int#    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
Prelude> :i Integer
data Integer
  = integer-gmp-1.0.2.0:GHC.Integer.Type.S# Int#
  | integer-gmp-1.0.2.0:GHC.Integer.Type.Jp# {-# UNPACK #-}integer-gmp-1.0.2.0:GHC.Integer.Type.BigNat
  | integer-gmp-1.0.2.0:GHC.Integer.Type.Jn# {-# UNPACK #-}integer-gmp-1.0.2.0:GHC.Integer.Type.BigNat
    -- Defined in ‘integer-gmp-1.0.2.0:GHC.Integer.Type’
```

As you can see, there are data constructors (and they are not *that* invisible!) for `Int` and `Integer`. We can use the one for `Int` no problem.

```
Prelude> :set -XMagicHash
Prelude> :t 3#
3# :: GHC.Prim.Int#
Prelude> :t GHC.Types.I# 3#
GHC.Types.I# 3# :: Int
Prelude> show 3
"3"
Prelude> show $ GHC.Types.I# 3#
"3"
```

OK we have built an `Int` with a constructor, which doesn't interfere with showing it as a plain `3` one little bit. It is an application of a bona fide constructor to an honest monomorphic literal. What about `Integer`?

```
Prelude> GHC.Integer.Type.S# 3#

<interactive>:16:1: error:
    Not in scope: data constructor ‘GHC.Integer.Type.S#’
    No module named ‘GHC.Integer.Type’ is imported.
Prelude>
```

Hmm.

```
Prelude> :m + GHC.Integer.Type

<no location info>: error:
    Could not load module ‘GHC.Integer.Type’
    it is a hidden module in the package ‘integer-gmp-1.0.2.0’
```

So `Integer` constructors are hidden from the programmer (intentionally I suppose). But if you were writing `GHC.Integer.Type` itself you would be able to use `GHC.Integer.Type.S# 3#`. This has type `Integer` and is again an application of a bona fide constructor to an honest monomorphic literal.

Comment: Thank you for the sleuthing inside GHC.

Comment: Remember that [a little bit of Template Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/true-name) will let you get at those hidden constructors anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`4 :: Integer` is such a value; `4 :: Int` is not. Don't confuse the literal `4` with the family of actual values that it represents in source code.

`4` by itself has the polymorphic type `Num a => a`, which means in the right context, you can "extract" from it a value of type `4 :: Integer`. Such a context is a call to `fromInteger`, since it expects a value of type `Integer` as an argument, not a value of type `Num a => a`.

When you write `x = 4` after declaring that `x` is, indeed, a value of type `Integer`, the compiler takes care of "extracting" the value `4 :: Integer` for your from the literal.

---

`MkAge` is necessary for type checking. `mkAge2 4` works precisely because you have defined (or at least derived) an instance of `Num` for `Age`, which entails defining `fromInteger :: Integer -> Age`. `mkAge2` is implicitly calling `fromInteger` on `4` to return `MkAge 4`, and *that* is the value passed to `mkAge2`. So you still need `MkAge`, you just don't have to *use* it explicitly.

Comment: I think you're just telling me what I already wrote in the q, but putting it rather confusingly. Can I write "the appropriate value" in Haskell source code? `4 :: Integer` yields that value; there's an invisible `fromInteger 4?` hidden in the bare `4`, so it's not writing the appropriate value direct.

Comment: I think the part you are asking about is that you too literally trying to use `fromInteger`. In Haskell *source code*, you would need some magical literal `4?` to avoid infinite recursion. But the compiler isn't limited to source code; it can work with the correct value internally that the literal `4` implies, and call `fromInteger` directly on that.